# Firebase performance - fetching nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Two firebase performance questions:

1. Docs refer to flat data is best practice when constructing data. However, if I wish to retrieve a few nodes of data together (a JOIN query in SQL), this means a few network requests. Is Firebase optimizing such use case (in server/client side)? How?
2. When fetching a specific node, using its full path, is there any need of indexing it? (Docs refer to actual queries, and I'm not sure this case applies as a query)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a "client-side join" in Firebase is not nearly as expensive as you might expect. See this answer: [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)

If you directly access the node (only calling `new Firebase()` and `child()`), no query is needed, so you won't need an index. If you're calling `orderByChild()` or `orderByValue()` you should add an index.

Comment: thanks a lot. Are there any firebase "under-the-hood" references regarding such use-cases and similar?